# Android Studio - blank menu items on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, intellij-idea, android-studio

When hovered over File menu or any other menu item  in android studio , it appears blank .I m running Android Studio 0.3.6 on Ubuntu 12.10 . The screenshot is here http://postimg.org/image/uer5zez0b/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got similar problem. But it's easy to fix.

Go to your Android Studio directory. Find file **idea.properties** (**bin** directory) and add one line at the end:

```
linux.native.menu=false
```

Now you should see working menu.

Comment: woot! Pretty menus with icons again. :P

Comment: that menu came back . But meanwhile , this trick helped to get the menu items . Press ALT+4 -> it will ask for a close window . click no and then you will see the menu again .